# handsontable Js update cell synonization

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I want to show same value on column E when I update column B. For example when I write anything on column B row ('test') then same value will update on column E cell("test").

[image: Doubt]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq687.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use afterChange hook like this example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur0kmdqp/) :

```
hot.addHook('afterChange', function(changes, source) {
  if (changes != null) {
    changes.forEach(function(item) {
      if (hot.propToCol(item[1]) == 1) {
        hot.setDataAtCell(item[0], 3, item[3]);
      }
    });
  }
}), hot;
```